# Do we need a canonical scam question?

Tags: discussion

We regularly receive questions regarding scams of one sort or another.  Usually these take the form of either:-

> Is example.com a scam site?

or

> I've lost XLM to example.com, can I get it back?

The answer to the latter is usually simply *No*.

Would it help if we had a canonical list question on which all known or suspected scam sites were listed?
This could either be on the main site or here on Meta.

All the existing questions could then be merged into it and future such questions would be duplicates of the new one.
I would expect it to be marked as Community Wiki.

Arguments for or against please.